# In a chess game should the piece move or should the board move the piece

Tags: java

I am building a chess game using java (probably not going use any gui or anything just a simple console game) but I have the ChessBoard class which is like this:

```
public class ChessBoard {

        private BasePiece[][] board = new BasePiece[8][8];

        private int charToInt(char input){
            return (int)input - 97;
        }

        public void setPiece(String colour, String type, char x, int y){
            board[charToInt(x)][y-1] = new BasePiece(colour, type);
        }

        public void setPiece(String piece, char x, int y){
            board[charToInt(x)][y-1] = new BasePiece(piece);
        }

        public String getPiece(char x, int y){
            return board[charToInt(x)][y-1].getPiece();
        }

    }
```

which is currently just very simple code to be able to add pieces to the board and then print out what piece is in any given location, but then I also have a ChessPiece class like this:

```
public class ChessPiece {
    private String colour;
    private String type;

    ChessPiece(String colour, String type){
        setColour(colour);
        setType(type);
    }

    ChessPiece(String piece){
        setColour(piece.toCharArray()[0]);
        setType(piece.toCharArray()[1]);
    }

    private void setColour(String colour){
        this.colour = colour.toLowerCase();
    }

    private void setColour(char colour){
        switch (colour) {
            case 'w':
                setColour("white");
                break;
            case 'b':
                setColour("black");
                break;
            default:
                setColour("invalid colour");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void setType(String type){
        this.type = type.toLowerCase();
    }

    private void setType(char type){
        switch (type) {
            case 'K':
                setType("king");
                break;
            case 'q':
                setType("queen");
                break;
            case 'r':
                setType("rook");
                break;
            case 'b':
                setType("bishop");
                break;
            case 'k':
                setType("knight");
                break;
            case 'p':
                setType("pawn");
                break;
            default:
                setType("invalid type");
                break;
        }
    }

    public String getColour(){
        return colour;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public String getPiece(){
        return getColour() + " " + getType();
    }
}
```

of which everything works so far, but I was wondering would it be better to have the chess pieces move (So have the moving be in the ChessPiece class) or just have how they can move in the ChessPiece class but then give the actual job of moving them to the ChessBoard class
Thanks

Comment: I think that your OOP structure needs beefing up.  The Player object (which could represent a human or computer player) should propose a move that the Game object verifies is legal after querying the state of the Board. If legal, then the Game object should allow the move, do any actions relevant to the move (capture a piece, check for and announce check, check for and announce 
 checkmate), and toggle the currentPlayer to the next Player in the game.

Comment: I'd have the board handle movement. Pieces don't need to know their location do they? I think involving them in that process will just complicate things.

Comment: I totally agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels, the player should move the piece.
I also strongly suggest you to use enums to handle the colour and the type of piece

Comment: Not only does the piece not know its current location, it doesn't know the locations of the other pieces, so it can't check to see if the move is legal.

Comment: The game object should have knowledge of the board, the piece positions, the captured pieces, whose move it is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, I think that your OOP structure is perhaps a bit too simplistic. I would recommend that you consider creating:

- enum ChessColor: WHITE, BLACK. Better to use an enum rather than Strings as the latter are error prone and don't allow for method parameter and other compile-time type-checking
- abstract class AbstractChessPiece: abstract class that the pieces extend from. It has a ChessColor field, and any other abstract methods that all pieces need. May not need this actually.
- enum ChessPiece extends AbstractChessPiece: Might as well make an enum of this since they will be constants. Will have several methods includine `public boolean moveAllowed(ChessSquare square)` that returns true if a move is allowed for this piece.
- class ChessSquare: it knows its own rank and file (int fields) with getters and setters, and has a ChessPiece field that is null if the square is empty or holds a ChessPiece if not.
- class ChessBoard: holds a grid of ChessSquares
- class ChessPlayer: that represents one of the two players. It has a ChessColor field, a `List<ChessPiece> capturedPieces`, methods for making moves, for proposing a draw, for capitulating...
- class ChessGame: the program that starts everything and controls the game flow. The player whose move it is, will propose a move to the game object which will check validity, and if valid, make the move and check for game result from the move, including capture, check, checkmate,...

---

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `computer style chess notation` to help you answer the question which is four characters denoted by this regular expression `"^[a-h][1-8][a-h][1-8]$"`: For instance, `e1g1` denotes that White castles kingside and `e8c8` denotes that Black castles queenside.

We use this `computer style chess notation` because it is easy to convert back and forth from a number.

Also note that the `en passant` move requires an `unusual capture`.